# Ошибка duplicate entry for key

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы `items` и `format_file`.

`items`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`format_file`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю соединения между `items.id_format_file` и `format_file.id`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я добавляю две записи с одним и тем же форматом файлов, выскакивает такая ошибка, работаю в `HeidiSQL`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат SHOW CREATE TABLE items

```
    CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `link` text NOT NULL,
  `owner` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_end` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext,
  `id_format_file` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_format_file` (`id_format_file`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_items_format_file` FOREIGN KEY (`id_format_file`) REFERENCES `format_file` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: выполните команду SHOW CREATE TABLE items и покажите результат

Comment: результат добавил в конце вопроса

Comment: собственно логично.....`UNIQUE KEY id_format_file`  значение поля должно быть уникальным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот и ответ на ваш проблему

```
UNIQUE KEY `id_format_file` (`id_format_file`),
```

вы поставили требование на проверку уникальности записи и поэтому вы не можете записать запись с одним и тем же ключом